# Bootstrap CSS Pull-Right issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very simple piece of code that I am trying to get to work and its giving me issues.

I have a grid of 9 and 3 set up. 9 being the tool title and 3 being the status of the tool.

In the code below however, even though I am using `pull-right` to get the content to the right side of the `col-md-3` the content within that isn't aligned to the right like I expect it to be.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5yctnw0/2/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h1 class="toolTitle">Tool Title <small class="toolSubTitle">#244</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><span class="pull-right"><h4>Active</h4>(dates & replacement if applicable)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would expect:

[image]

I know this is going to be a silly css attribute I am missing but not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

The content is aligned to the right but the text is not right aligned. Use `text-right` css class to right align the text.

```
<span class="pull-right text-right">
  <h4>Active</h4>
  (dates & replacement if applicable)
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use let the text to the right:

```
 .col-md-3 {text-align:right}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p5yctnw0/5/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/p5yctnw0/3/

Use the class `text-right` when it comes to text. `pull-right` is for divs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it pulls the div right, but the spans are still left aligned within the div.
Split the div into 2 spans, one for each line.

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="pull-right">
    <h4>Active</h4>
  </span>
  <span class="pull-right">(dates & replacement if applicable)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are looking for is `text-align:right` . Use it to get your desired output. If you want both the span and the trailing text to be pulled right, use @van-tuan-pham 's answer. Or use only to the span.

But do not override bootstrap classes. Instead use your own class or id selectors to set css attributes.

Answer (score 0):

simply do like this way

```css
.alignment {
 text-align:right;
}
.alignment span {
 display:block;
 font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h1 class="toolTitle">Tool Title <small class="toolSubTitle">#244</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 alignment">
     <h4>Active <span>(dates & replacement if applicable)</span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace row div your code with following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h1 class="toolTitle">Tool Title <small class="toolSubTitle">#244</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right" ><span><h4>Active</h4>(dates & replacement if applicable)</span></div>
  </div>
```